Bash: convert comma seperated ips into array of ip
I am getting comma seperated IPs as a string in my application from terraform. I need to replace variable in a conf file with array of ips. Number ips can be anything. I have taken 2 as an example.
Script.sh:
#!/bin/bash
var_ips="10.10.10.177,10.10.10.181"

IFS=','
read -ra ip_array <<< "$var_ips"
form_hosts=()
for item in "${ip_array[@]}";do
     form_hosts+=("\"$item\"")
done 

sed -i "s/^hosts: \"from_terraform_hosts\"$/hosts: [${form_hosts[*]}]/g" host.conf

host.conf
hosts: "from_terraform_hosts"
//file truncated

Here i want entry in host.conf as
hosts: ["10.10.10.177","10.10.10.181"]

but i am getting
hosts: ["10.10.10.177" "10.10.10.181"]

Comma is missing when i substitute the values. Can anyone help to fix above issue.
The difference is due to below
echo [${form_hosts[*]}]
echo "[${form_hosts[*]}]"

Output
["10.10.10.177" "10.10.10.181"]
["10.10.10.177", "10.10.10.181"]

Here under double quotes only comma is coming but i cant use this way inside sed command.

Couldn’t you just replace commas in $var_ips, rather than converting to and from a Bash array, e.g. something like echo "[\"${var_ips/,/\",\"}\"]"?

@Biffen result is still same when we use in substituting the value in sed. thats is comma is missing.

@LOrD_ARaGOrN I don’t know what you did, but sed "s/^hosts: \"from_terraform_hosts\"$/hosts: [\"${var_ips/,/\",\"}\"]/g" host.conf gives me hosts: ["10.10.10.177","10.10.10.181"] (no arrays or anything; just set $var_ips and then sed).

@biffen you are very close. its working but it dont work if number of ip gets change to 1 or 3 or more. It should be generic

@LOrD_ARaGOrN sed "s/^hosts: \"from_terraform_hosts\"$/hosts: [\"${var_ips//,/\",\"}\"]/g" host.conf works for any* number. Note the added /. (*I tried it with 1, 2, 3 and 4.)

Super Biffen. Thanks

Why don't you define it as array in the first place? var_ips=( 10.10.10.177 10.10.10.181 )"

@user1934428 for testing purpose only i defined it. However, i am getting it in my application from terraform, which send in string format only.

In this case, I would first convert the string to an array: IFS=, ips_arr=( $var_ips ).

You can do it with Bash’s parameter expansion, no arrays needed:
#!/bin/bash

var_ips="10.10.10.177,10.10.10.181"

sed -i "s/^hosts: \"from_terraform_hosts\"$/hosts: [\"${var_ips//,/\",\"}\"]/g" host.conf

${var_ips//,/\",\"} expands $var_ips but replaces commas with "," and the sed replacement wraps it in [" and "].
Note that this’ll only work as long as $var_ips doesn’t contain any ‘funny stuff’, e.g. spaces (they would end up inside the quotes) or regex-special characters (they would break the sed command).
